# Characterising all normal matrices in $M_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: matrices, inner-products, orthogonality, diagonalization, orthonormal

> Characterise all normal matrices in $M_2(\mathbb R)$

Motivated from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840502/how-can-i-find-the-general-form-of-an-orthogonal-matrix/2840511?noredirect=1#comment7060459_2840511), and José Carlos Santos really nice answer to it, I have made this post.

It is my first time making such a post so I don't really know if it would be allowed.

I have nothing to add regarding the characterisation.

It would be really nice to have a characterisation for all $2\times2$ real normal matrices as it would make coming up with counter examples to certain problems quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is normal if and only if$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}b^2=c^2\\(b-c)(a-d)=0.\end{array}\right.$$It is not hard to see that therefore the $2\times2$ normal matrices are:

1. The symmetric matrices.
2. The matrices of the type $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Diagonal matrices are a subset of symmetric ones, why make them explicit?

Comment: That **was** silly. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I'm missing something.